# apache .gz gzip content handler for Linux documentation /usr/share/doc and localhost/doc/

Tags: apache, gzip, handler, content-type

How could I create a simple content handler for apache .gz gzip content. I want it to uncompress say http://localhost/doc/FAQ/Linux-FAQ.gz and send it to the browser as plain text. There is a lot of documentation for Linux in /usr/share/doc and localhost/doc/. I don't want to use zless, zcat or vim to read the content. I use apache to browse the documentation on my local machine and have my web browser revive it as standard text so that it does not ask me to download the *.gz file every time.

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
Alias local.doc "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

But Now I want all those .gz file under /usr/share/doc/ to be servered as plain text. I think I could do that very simply with a python script in cgi-bin. I am looking for a nice content handler for those files. Like the way it php files are handled .gz should be uncompressed and sent to the browser.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

I see there is a mod_deflate, how would this apply. Could this handle the gzip content.

It would make browsing documentation so much easier. Any programing resources to help here would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used something like this before for js/css files (I modified the below to match your needs).  Add this to your virtualhost entry:

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
Alias local.doc "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory /usr/share/doc>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128

    AddEncoding gzip gz
    <FilesMatch "\.gz$">
      ForceType text/plain
      Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Updated above to match your code

In ubuntu ensure that Headers module is enabled

```
$ sudo a2enmod headers  
$ sudo a2enmod deflate
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Update2: Realized that "AddEncoding gzip gz" was missing.. otherwise, file kept trying to download.

Update3: Added apache module deflate install command. Here's my deflate.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      # these are known to be safe with MSIE 6
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

      # everything else may cause problems with MSIE 6
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
</IfModule>
```

You could first try with some other type of file (e.g. a css file). Example:

```
cd /usr/share/doc
cat ".styles { width: 50px; }" > test.css
gzip -c test.css > test.css.gz
```

Add this to your virtualhost:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.css\.gz$">
        ForceType text/css
        Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    </FilesMatch>
```

Test http://127.0.0.1/doc/test.css and http://127.0.0.1/doc/test.css.gz and see what result you get.

Comment: @dolan could I put the <filesmatch> section in the <Directory > section I have above.

Comment: @nelaar as far as I know, that should work fine.. I updated my post to include your code. Post back if that doesn't work

Comment: Syntax error on line 41 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

41 Header set Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: I'd guess the apache module headers or rewrite is missing.. but here is my complete list to help debug what is missing: alias, autoindex, cgi, dir, env, expires, headers, mime, negotiation, rewrite, setenvif, status (go to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ , at least on an ubuntu server to see what is installed)

Comment: @dolan that fixed the error but sorry it is not working as I expected. My browsers are still trying to download the files. The web server is not sending it as plain text.

Comment: I need to uncompress the file on the server side and then send it. I think some code needs to written to do that.

Comment: I know with my CSS & JS files, they are compressed in the folder, and Apache is uncompressing them when they are requested.  If nobody else has a better idea what the problem is, I'll check back tomorrow mornining, with some testing on my end.. need some sleep first :)

Comment: Okay, I was finally able to get this working.  I was missing "AddEncoding gzip gz".  See my updated answer with this included.  I got this working for /usr/share/doc as well (e.g. http://localhost/doc/yelp/NEWS.gz)

Comment: @dolan which browser are you using, and have you changed any settings in it. Just want to double check that we are working in similar setups. I am testing using firefox 3.6.3, and chrome 8.0.552.237, chromium 5.0.342.9.

Comment: @nelaar I'm using FF 3.6.14 & Chrome 9.0.597.107 on Windows 7 64-bit. My Linux box is Ubuntu 10.04 w/ Apache2, w/ default virtual host and the above additions, and the following modules: alias, auth_basic, authn_file, authz_default, authz_groupfile, authz_host, authz_user, autoindex, cgid, deflate, dir, env, headers, mime, negotiation, reqtimeout, rewrite, setenvif, status.  I just realized, I didn't mention "deflate" module. Be sure you have that. One other thing, try a gz file you haven't tried yet (Chrome was kept downloading ones I tried before I got it working)

Comment: @dolan can you post $ cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf

Comment: @dolan have the necessary modules headers, deflate, here is a complete list of my modules ubuntu 10.04 alias auth_basic authn_file authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex cgi deflate dir env expires headers jk mime mod_mono negotiation perl php5 python reqtimeout ruby setenvif status.
as you can see I have few extras for the other stuff I am messing with

Comment: @nelaar deflate.conf posted in answer.  "rewrite" shouldn't be needed, that's only one i see that you don't have.  Did you try accessing a file you haven't tried yet? What brought me to my solution is I tried with a "css" file first. Maybe give that a try. I'll post some code in the answer

Comment: @dolan thanks your test works, will keep trying to figure out why it is not working for other /usr/share/doc/*/*.gz files.

Comment: ForceType plain/text I expect the problems i am still having have to do with the mime types, which are partially controlled by /etc/mime.types.

Comment: What O/S are you running Apache on? As noted earlier, my setup is on Ubuntu 10.04 w/ standard apache2 from apt-get

Comment: @dolan Ubuntu 10.04 2.6.32-28-generic Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Comment: @dolan I have looked at the cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf | head -n 30. Can I see yours.

Comment: @dolan got it working changed the forcetype dirctive to ForceType text/plain from ForceType plain/text

Comment: @dolan thanks for all your help. I will go and check out some of your other answers and upvote the ones that seam reasonable to me. For all your effort try to give you a bit more rep.

Comment: @nelaar awesome on getting it working!  No worries on the help, my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf | head -n 30
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

#
# TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
# filename extension to MIME-type.
#
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

#
# AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
# file mime.types for specific file types.
#
#AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
#
# AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
# information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
# Despite the name similarity, the following Add* directives have
# nothing to do with the FancyIndexing customization directives above.
#
AddEncoding x-compress .Z
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddEncoding x-bzip2 .bz2
#
# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-bzip2 .bz2
```

Comment: I uncommented mine. It is still giving me problems

Comment: For me, it works after you comment away the lines starting with `AddType`.